# Fastest way of counting number of documents for Lucene term

Tags: java, lucene

I want to count the number of documents in Lucene for a term on a field.
I know 3 ways of doing that; I am curious what the best and fastest practice would be:

I will search in a long-typed single-valued field ("field") for the term  (so not text, but numbered data!)

#### Some pre-code any of below examples will use first:

```
Directory dirIndex = FSDirectory.open('/path/to/index/');
IndexReader indexReader = DirectoryReader.open(dirIndex);
final BytesRefBuilder bytes = new BytesRefBuilder(); 
NumericUtils.longToPrefixCoded(Long.valueOf(longTerm).longValue(),0,bytes);
```

#### 1) use docFreq() from Index

```
TermsEnum termEnum = MultiFields.getTerms(indexReader, "field").iterator(null);
termEnum.seekExact(bytes.toBytesRef());
int count = termEnum.docFreq();
```

#### 2) Search for it

```
IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(indexReader);
TermQuery query = new TermQuery(new Term("field", bytes.toBytesRef()));
TotalHitCountCollector collector = new TotalHitCountCollector();
searcher.search(query,collector);
int count = collector.getTotalHits();
```

#### 3) Read exact match from index and count the docs one by one

```
TermsEnum termEnum = MultiFields.getTerms(indexReader, "field").iterator(null);
termEnum.seekExact(bytes.toBytesRef());
Bits liveDocs = MultiFields.getLiveDocs(indexReader);
DocsEnum docsEnum = termEnum.docs(liveDocs, null);
int count = 0;
if (docsEnum != null) {
    int docx;
    while ((docx = docsEnum.nextDoc()) != DocIdSetIterator.NO_MORE_DOCS) {
        count++;
    }
 }
```

#### Best method

option 1) wins for shortest code, but is basically useless if you ever update and delete documents in your index. it counts deleted docs as if they're still there. Not documented in many places (except the official documentation, but not in in answers here on s.o.) that this is something to be aware of. Perhaps there is a way around this, otherwise the enthusiasm about this method is a bit misplaced.
option 2) and 3) do produce the correct results, but which should be preferred? or better yet - is there a faster way of doing this?

Comment: Have you compared the performance of 2) and 3)? Personally I'd probably choose 2) and I think that's the "official" way to do it.

Comment: I'm afraid the caching mechanism of Lucene may trouble the results when measuring performance. Would be tricky to do.

Comment: The point is to measure it exactly the way you plan to use it.

Comment: Difficulty with measuring is: if I first get those values for DocId 1 using option 2 and then option 3, the system may have cached it for option 2, so option 3 uses cache and appears faster. 
Ok, so I used System.nanoTime() to measure before and after for both option 2 and 3. On average for 100 cases, option 3 is 8* faster! Even if I run it a few times on the same docs, which would've left it in the cache I suppose for the second run to both benefit from it. It makes sense, reading numeric exact values doesn't require any normalization, so probably the searcher is creating unnecessary overhead

Comment: And now we've both learned something :) I suggest writing your own answer with this valuable finding. If possible, include your testing code so people can corroborate the claim.

Comment: Done so - only doubt left on the table is if option 2) perhaps is ranking results, which is not needed for document counting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Measured by doing a test, using the index to fetch the docs rather than search for them (i.e. option 3 instead of option 2) appears to be faster (average: **option 3) was 8 times faster in a 100 doc sample** I could run). 
I've also reversed the test to ensure that running one before the other doesn't affect results: it doesn't.

So it appears the searcher is creating quite some overhead to perform a simple document count, and if one looks into counting docs for a single term entry, a lookup in the index is fastest.

code used to test (using first 100 records in SOLR index):

```
import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexReader;
import org.apache.lucene.index.DirectoryReader;
import org.apache.lucene.index.Fields;
import org.apache.lucene.index.DocsEnum;
import org.apache.lucene.document.Document;
import org.apache.lucene.index.TermsEnum;
import org.apache.lucene.index.Term;
import org.apache.lucene.index.MultiFields;
import org.apache.lucene.util.BytesRef;
import org.apache.lucene.util.BytesRefBuilder;
import org.apache.lucene.util.NumericUtils;
import org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.ParseException;
import org.apache.lucene.store.Directory;
import org.apache.lucene.store.FSDirectory;
import org.apache.lucene.search.DocIdSetIterator;
import org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher;
import org.apache.lucene.search.TermQuery;
import org.apache.lucene.search.TotalHitCountCollector;
import org.apache.lucene.util.Bits;
import org.apache.lucene.index.MultiFields;

public class ReadLongTermReferenceCount {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Directory dirIndex = FSDirectory.open('/path/to/index/');
        IndexReader indexReader = DirectoryReader.open(dirIndex);
        final BytesRefBuilder bytes = new BytesRefBuilder(); 


        TermsEnum termEnum = MultiFields.getTerms(indexReader, "field").iterator(null);

        IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(indexReader);
        TotalHitCountCollector collector = new TotalHitCountCollector();

        Bits liveDocs = MultiFields.getLiveDocs(indexReader);
        final BytesRefBuilder bytes = new BytesRefBuilder(); // for reuse!
        int maxDoc = indexReader.maxDoc();
        int docsPassed = 0;
        for (int i=0; i<maxDoc; i++) {
            if (docsPassed==100) {
                break;
            }
            if (liveDocs != null && !liveDocs.get(i))
                continue;
            Document doc = indexReader.document(i);

            //get longTerm from this doc and convert to BytesRefBuilder
            String longTerm = doc.get("longTerm");
            NumericUtils.longToPrefixCoded(Long.valueOf(longTerm).longValue(),0,bytes);

            //time before the first test
            long time_start = System.nanoTime();

            //look in the "field" index for longTerm and count the number of documents
            int count = 0;
            termEnum.seekExact(bytes.toBytesRef());
            DocsEnum docsEnum = termEnum.docs(liveDocs, null);
            if (docsEnum != null) {
                int docx;
                while ((docx = docsEnum.nextDoc()) != DocIdSetIterator.NO_MORE_DOCS) {
                    count++;
                }
            }

            //mid point: test 1 done, start of test 2
            long time_mid = System.nanoTime();

            //do a search for longTerm in "field"
            TermQuery query = new TermQuery(new Term("field", bytes.toBytesRef()));
            searcher.search(query,collector);
            int count = collector.getTotalHits();

            //end point: test 2 done.
            long time_end = System.nanoTime();

            //write to stdout
            System.out.println(longTerm+"\t"+(time_mid-time_start)+"\t"+(time_end-time_mid));

            docsPassed++;
        }
        indexReader.close();
        dirIndex.close();
    }
}
```

Slight modification of above to work with Lucene 5:

```
import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexReader;
import org.apache.lucene.index.DirectoryReader;
import org.apache.lucene.index.Fields;
import org.apache.lucene.index.PostingsEnum;
import org.apache.lucene.document.Document;
import org.apache.lucene.index.TermsEnum;
import org.apache.lucene.index.Term;
import org.apache.lucene.index.MultiFields;
import org.apache.lucene.util.BytesRef;
import org.apache.lucene.util.BytesRefBuilder;
import org.apache.lucene.util.NumericUtils;
import org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.ParseException;
import org.apache.lucene.store.Directory;
import org.apache.lucene.store.FSDirectory;
import org.apache.lucene.search.DocIdSetIterator;
import org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher;
import org.apache.lucene.search.TermQuery;
import org.apache.lucene.search.TotalHitCountCollector;
import org.apache.lucene.util.Bits;
import org.apache.lucene.index.MultiFields;

public class ReadLongTermReferenceCount {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Directory dirIndex = FSDirectory.open(Paths.get('/path/to/index/'));
        IndexReader indexReader = DirectoryReader.open(dirIndex);
        final BytesRefBuilder bytes = new BytesRefBuilder(); 


        TermsEnum termEnum = MultiFields.getTerms(indexReader, "field").iterator(null);

        IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(indexReader);
        TotalHitCountCollector collector = new TotalHitCountCollector();

        Bits liveDocs = MultiFields.getLiveDocs(indexReader);
        final BytesRefBuilder bytes = new BytesRefBuilder(); // for reuse!
        int maxDoc = indexReader.maxDoc();
        int docsPassed = 0;
        for (int i=0; i<maxDoc; i++) {
            if (docsPassed==100) {
                break;
            }
            if (liveDocs != null && !liveDocs.get(i))
                continue;
            Document doc = indexReader.document(i);

            //get longTerm from this doc and convert to BytesRefBuilder
            String longTerm = doc.get("longTerm");
            NumericUtils.longToPrefixCoded(Long.valueOf(longTerm).longValue(),0,bytes);

            //time before the first test
            long time_start = System.nanoTime();

            //look in the "field" index for longTerm and count the number of documents
            int count = 0;
            termEnum.seekExact(bytes.toBytesRef());
            PostingsEnum docsEnum = termEnum.postings(liveDocs, null);
            if (docsEnum != null) {
                int docx;
                while ((docx = docsEnum.nextDoc()) != DocIdSetIterator.NO_MORE_DOCS) {
                    count++;
                }
            }

            //mid point: test 1 done, start of test 2
            long time_mid = System.nanoTime();

            //do a search for longTerm in "field"
            TermQuery query = new TermQuery(new Term("field", bytes.toBytesRef()));
            searcher.search(query,collector);
            int count = collector.getTotalHits();

            //end point: test 2 done.
            long time_end = System.nanoTime();

            //write to stdout
            System.out.println(longTerm+"\t"+(time_mid-time_start)+"\t"+(time_end-time_mid));

            docsPassed++;
        }
        indexReader.close();
        dirIndex.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm quite surprised by this. Could you post your test code?

Comment: Have done so. I havent ran above code just now, as I've done the test and moved on, but this should be it.